# IIS 7.5 Windows integrated authentication confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

How is this possible to display NTLM and Kerberos AuthenticationType when executing this code when debugging in VS2010:

```
IIdentity WinId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
WindowsIdentity currentIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

lblUserName.Text ="User NAme: " + WinId.Name;
lblIsAuthenticated.Text = "Is Authenticated: " + WinId.IsAuthenticated.ToString();
lbluthentiationType.Text = "Authetication type: " + WinId.AuthenticationType;
lblAuthenticationType2.Text = "Authentication Type: " + currentIdentity.AuthenticationType;
```

When I look in local server it shows Negotiate on both lblAuthenticatinType and lblAuthenticatinType2

also

I am only able to see authenticated users when accessing the web server by IP (172.0.0.10:1111) and 401.1 when accessig by servername:1111 and servername.domain.com:1111

I don't know where to bit this. I have enabled authentication in web.config as follows

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
    <!--<identity impersonate="true" userName="<domain>\<UserName>" password="<password>"/>-->
</authentication>
<authorization>       
    <!--<allow users="domain\user.name" /><allow roles="domain\Users" />-->
    <allow users="?" />    
</authorization>
```

Comment: Are you saying that `WinId.AuthenticationType` and `currentIdentity.AuthenticationType` indicate that both NTLM and Kerberos are in effect at the same time?

Comment: Yes that what's happening. any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: What is the username of the `currentIdentity`? If memory serves, one of those will be the authenticated user, the other can be the identity of the account the Application Pool is running under.